# Verify the coherence of date with Unix Shell

Tags: linux, shell, validation, date, unix

I have done a shell script to validate the coherence of a date (not the fromat) like that:

```
DATE="20131231"
date -d "${DATE}" "+%Y/%m/%d" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "INVALID DATE!"
else 
    echo "VALID DATE"
fi
```

The wanted result is OK under GNU/Linux and Unix/OpenSolaris 10.

```
DATE="20131231" ==> VALID DATE 

DATE="20131232" ==> INVALID DATE! 

DATE="20131331" ==> INVALID DATE!
```

But is not OK under IBM AIX OS. It always display "INVALID DATE!".

```
DATE="20131231" ==> INVALID DATE! 

DATE="20131232" ==> INVALID DATE! 

DATE="20131331" ==> INVALID DATE!
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: `date -d` is a GNU/Linux extension. In POSIX `date can be used either to set the system date or to print out the current date and time.

Comment: Don't throw away error messages while you're debugging problems!  The AIX `date` is probably telling you that you're using an invalid option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent enough Perl distribution (5.10 I think), this is likely very portable:

```
$ validate_date() {
    perl -MTime::Piece -e '
        eval {Time::Piece->strptime(q{'"$1"'}, "%Y%m%d")}; 
        exit 1 if $@
    '
}
$ date=20131231; validate_date $date && echo VALID || echo INVALID
VALID
$ date=20131232; validate_date $date && echo VALID || echo INVALID
INVALID
$ date=20131233; validate_date $date && echo VALID || echo INVALID
INVALID
```